# Sitecore WFFM make 1 of 2 fields required

Tags: validation, webforms, sitecore

I'm trying to create a WFFM form and I need to set one of two fields to be required. Do I need to create custom fields? Or is this something that I can achieve with the module itself?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use the [Morph module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/M/Morph.aspx), which you can download from the Sitecore Marketplace.

From it's description:

> Selection-dependent inputs require users to enter additional
> information related to an initial selection before they can complete a
> form. In almost all cases, it allows making web forms simpler and more
> responsive to user actions and personalizing forms depending on
> visitors’ features.

If memory serves it uses the Sitecore Rules Engine to decide which fields to show/ hide based on inputs. However, I'm not 100% sure whether you can use the `Required` checkbox there, but worth a try.

Comment: Nice, that not seen this module before... wish they would integrate it!

Comment: I'll investigate and give it a go. Off topic: Problem with some marketplace modules though is that they are not supported by sitecore. Therefore some will have objections to use it in prod.

Answer (score 0):

No custom field types are needed. The WFFM Form Designer has a `Required` checkbox for each field row and most standard fields support this along with a custom validation message.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I can make one field required but my question is if I can make 1 of 2 fields required - Basically I want users to fill either mobile or phone fields.

Comment: Ahh. You could make a form level validator by inheriting from `BaseSaveAction` perhaps?

Comment: That might be the way to go... I'm trying to understand the limitations of this module as is.